# How to parse "on en a de la chance"?

Tags: pronoms

> Le temps idéal pour une promenade. On **en** a de la chance.

I'm in two minds about the function of the "en":

1. > Le temps idéal pour une promenade. On a de la chance **d**'avoir le temps idéal.

The "en" refers to "**d**'avoir le temps idéal". In this case, however, I suppose the sentence should be phrased as "on a la chance d'avoir le temps idéal" without "de" before the "la".

2. > Le temps idéal pour une promenade. On en a,{***comma***} **de** la chance.

Here, the "en" serves as an emphasis, referring to "**de** la chance". But I notice the lack of a comma in the original sentence.

Comment: I think that the second version, the emphasis, is the correct way. In the very first sentence, *On en a de la chance*, we could drop the *en* without any problem. But more than only *de*, it's *de la chance*.

Comment: You are right about your second proposition. There should be a comma  but it's so much used that we probably often forget it. I have nothing to add to your analysis.

Comment: Hi. What do you think of the 1st interpretatoin?

Comment: It doesn't work. *On en a (de la chance, du courage, de l'argent)* is a set expression where *en* refer to what follows or is implicit (*Il en a*).

Comment: @jlliagre Hi. Regarding the *duality* of "*en ... de*", should I keep "*en*" when I say: "*Si des gens sont dans le besoin, est-ce qu’on ne s’**en** fiche/balance pas **de** savoir s’ils sont du Japon ou d'Allemagne ?*"

Comment: Using or dropping *en* are both possible here. (off-topic: "sont du Japon/d'Allemagne" is not very idiomatic, that would rather be *sont japonais/allemands* or *sont au Japon/en Allemagne* or *viennent du Japon, d'Allemagne*)

Comment: @jlliagre Got it, thanks. How do you say this part in English: "*Est-ce qu’on ne s’en fiche/balance pas de savoir s’ils ...*"? In English, it's kind of a double negative, negating "not care less" with another "not".

Comment: Maybe something like: "Don't we care less about the place they are from?"

Comment: Great prose here: [Je veux pas faire chier mais est-ce qu'on s'en bat pas les couilles de la couleur un peu](https://bichetterp.fr/forum/topic/15242/demande-de-recrutement-en-tant-que-recrue-dans-le-gign) ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre A nice link. See, the thing is that my girlfriend (despite long years of living in France) couldn't immediately process this construction that negates "s’en fiche/balance" (which is usually used in the affirmative). Do native speakers have any trouble wrapping their head around this negative construction if it is said quite fast in conversation, for instance?

Comment: The (double) negative is mandatory for the sentence to be understood as intended. *Est-ce qu'on s'en fiche de savoir...* would be a real, open question (answer: *oui, on s'en fiche* or *non, on s'en fiche pas*) while *Est-ce qu'on s'en fiche pas de savoir...* is rhetorical and its implicit answer is: *ouais, t'as raison. On s'en fiche*.

Comment: @jlliagre A great answer, or rather, a great comment. :D Perhaps not for you, but from an English speaker's (or, for that matter, a Russian speaker's) perspective, the negation of "s’en ficher/balancer" (as opposed to countless other verbs) doesn't come that easily. But now I could finally let it sink in!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I can help you. (TLDR below)

In fact, in this case : « On en a de la chance. », the « en » acts as a *pronom personnel*. It is a quite particular one like the « y » you can meet in « J'y suis allé ».

Both are used as a replacement for a complement (or even fo aslice of a sentence that could be huge)

« Je suis à cet endroit, je reste à cet endroit. » --> « J'y suis, j'y reste. »

« J'ai de la chance. » --> « J'en ai. »

The *en* and *y* are used when everyone inside the conversation understands at what these two pronouns refers to. They are totally implicit.

In your particular case, one could argue that it is a grammar/syntax mistake because they repeat the same information twice (*en* is supposed to replace *de la chance* ) In common french, people used to do it to put more emphasis on it.

TLDR : « en » is a way of implicit replacement of a part of the sentence everyone inside the conversation understands. Two letters that could replace from few words to a whole paragraph. In your example, the *en* and the words it is supposed to replace (*de la chance*) are both present. It is a mistake often made in common french to put emphasis on something which is so said twice.

The comma could be used if you want to be a proper grammar nazi. :)

« J'en ai, de la chance ». It becomes now a perfectly ponctuated sentence but semantically, it is still a mistake.

The form : « J'en ai de la chance » is still accepted and is certainly going to be the norm.

Answer (score 0):

It is your second guess. **en** refers to a quantity, a rough translation could be **some**.

The coma is still used quite often, but as it disappeared orally it influenced the writing and people tend to skip it. Though it sounds weird, it could be roughly translated as:

> We got **some**, luck!

as in

> Luck, we sure got **some**!

It is almost not used in english tho, and you would more easily say:

> We sure got lucky!